# R programming merge(add) values by dates?

Tags: r

I need merge values on "count" column of A data(month, count, desc) and B(month, count, desc) data to Merged data by "month" column. Some months present on both data, but some don't. For months present on both data, I need to add up values of count. For example: March "count"=21+5=26

I don't care about "desc" column.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can `rbind` the two datasets and use `aggregate` to get the `sum`

```
aggregate(count~month, data = rbind(df1, df2), FUN = sum)
```

---

Or use `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
        group_by(month) %>%
        summarise(count = sum(count))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[, .(count = sum(count)), by = month]
```